# SQLite: одинаковый размер базы вне зависимости от типа данных

Tags: sql, sqlite

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Создал базу "SQLite3", внутри создал 1 150 таблиц с однотипной структурой: 6 столбцов с типом ЧИСЛО и 2 столбца ДАТА.
В каждую таблицу ежедневно будут загружаться по 40 строк.

Обратил внимание, что вне зависимости от указанного типа данных и загружаемой информации файл БД всегда занимает одинаковый объем памяти:

1. 1-загрузка = 5,2 мб.
2. 2-загрузка = 7,5 мб.
3. 3-загрузка = 8,5 мб.
4. 4-загрузка = 10,1 мб.
5. 5-загрузка = 10,7 мб.

Итоговый размер БД не меняется, даже если в два из восьми столбцов вместо чисел загружать текст.
На этом же сайте попадалась информация, что "SQLite3" все данные хранит текстовом формате (и заявляет, что она БД с динамической типизацией).

Правильно ли понимаю, что в таком случае на размер базы никак не повлиять?

```py
def stat_to_db(keys):
    data_base = sqlite3.connect('api_keys.db')
    cursor = data_base.cursor()

    for key in keys:
        stat_request = get_stat(key)
        cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{key}' (
                    update_id integer,
                    update_time datetime,
                    method text,
                    limit_type text,
                    period_start_date date,
                    period_end_date date,
                    method_limit integer,
                    spent integer
                )""")

        # Определяем порядковый номер загрузки данных о статистике
        update_id = 1       # Если запись первая, то номер загрузки = 1
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT update_id FROM '{key}' ORDER BY update_id DESC")
        if cursor.fetchone():
            update_id = cursor.fetchone()[0] + 1       # Последующие загрузки на +1 больше

        # Обновляем данные статистики
        for method in stat_request:
            cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{key}' VALUES (
                {update_id},
                '{date_and_time()}',
                '{method['methodName']}',
                '{method['limitType']}',
                '{method['periodStartDate']}',
                '{method['periodEndDate']}',
                {method['limit']},
                {method['spent']}
                )""")
    data_base.commit()
    data_base.close()
```

Comment: Не занимайтесь фигнёй. Если мало места - просто поставьте более пухлый накопитель, благо они не миллион стоют...

Comment: Такой вариант понятен, но не кажется пока самым оптимальным. Проще сейчас выстроить нормальную структуру, чтобы при масштабировании не возникало доп. сложностей.

Если я правильно понял, то установка, например, MySQL может изменить объем БД, т.к. в этой БД у каждого столбца можно указать конкретный тип данных и под этот тип будет выделяться разных объем памяти, а SQLite сразу авансом резервирует место.

Comment: Ну Вы почитайте поглубже - вплоть до описания внутренней структуры файла БД. Особенно обратите внимание на то, что данные хранятся блоками, а не сплошным потоком. Так что в блок укладывается строго определённое количество записей и не больше. Но обычно меньше - в блоке обычно оставляется место под сколько-то неиспользуемых записей, это ускоряет вставку, снижая количество расщеплений. Как кластеры на диске... А потому зависимость объёма файла БД от структуры не столь прямая, как Вы думаете.

Comment: *Если я правильно понял, то установка, например, MySQL может изменить объем БД* Установка MySQL ну никаким образом не может изменить размер базы SQLite - даже теоретически. PS. Свежесозданная таблица в MySQL из одного числового поля и без записей занимает на диске 112 кб.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я предполагал, что нужно не просто установить другую БД, но конвертировать базу из SQLite в MySQL и далее использовать последнюю

Comment: *конвертировать базу из SQLite в MySQL* Простейшим изменением порядка копирования записей при конвертации можно получать в итоге размер файла таблицы MySQL на диске, различающийся не на проценты - в разы...

Comment: Пример. Таблица из 1 INT PK поля 100к записей от 1 до 100к. Простое копирование - итоговая таблица занимает 10 Мб. Копирование с ORDER BY RAND() - 12 Мб.

Comment: _она БД с динамической типизацией_ - да. _все данные хранит текстовом формате_ - нет. Из первого никак не вытекает второе.

Comment: У sqlite неплохая документация. Посмотрите [Architecture of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/arch.html), [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) - тут описано то, про что выше упоминал Akina: данные хранятся блоками, в страницах.

Comment: [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - вот на что особо обратите внимание: Type Affinity. Реально есть только типы TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL, BLOB. Все остальные приводятся к ним.